# Pyautogui Nonetype object is not subscriptable error message

Tags: python, bots, pyautogui, image-recognition

Every time I load my code I get the error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pmaze\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\bavl.py", line 12, in 
print(pyautogui.center(Fishposition))
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze_*init*_.py", line 582, in center
return Point(coords[0] + int(coords[2] / 2), coords[1] + int(coords[3] / 2))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
It makes no sense why it makes this

```
this is my code
`import pyautogui 
import time 
import keyboard 
import random
#pyautogui.locateOnScreen("Strike.png", confidence=0.5) != None:
        #print("I Can see where to fish")
        #pyautogui.press(' ') 
#wheretofish = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("fish.png", confidence=0.7)
Fishposition = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("fish.png", confidence=0.6)
while 1:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("fish.png", confidence=0.6) != None:
        print(pyautogui.center(Fishposition))
    else:
        print("I cannot see where to fish")
    time.sleep(1)
```

I have tried alot of diffrent functions but they wont work
What I want to happen is that pyautogui gives me the tupple of the fishes position and i want the exact x value of the center but when the code sees this image it just gives me that error message